# xterm window positioning

Tags: centos, xterm

I want a shortcut to start an xterm window with specified number of columns and rows and from the specified starting points.

I have `CentOS 6.6` and the xterm's version is: `X.Org 6.8.99.903(253)`. I don't know what else might affect its behaviour.

To achive my goal I simply created an xyz.desktop file with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Exec=xterm -fa 'Dejavu Sans Mono' -fs 18 -geometry 80x30+0+0 -e "torun"
```

This works exactly as expected on another machine with `CentOS 6.4`, same xterm version, same .desktop file, same .Xresources file. On this computer it just puts itself to somewhere in the middle of the screen with default window size.

Interestingly if I open a terminal (either xterm or gnome-terminal) to the screen and then double click on the launcher it positions itself rightly to the top left corner. Said open to screen because this won't work if I launch the xterm only minimized. However the settings for columns and rows will not change no matter if there is a terminal open or not. I can not find an explanation why won't it behave as expected.

Have anyone else met this behaviour and found the fix for it? Suggestions?

Comment: That sounds as if the window manager is interfering with the geometry settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie), this utility seems to be more stable to set the window's property.